# jQuery modal not setting horizontally middle

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a simple jQuery modal. It works well, but I can't set it horizontally middle. I've tried many approach, but it not centering anyway. It creates problem when I want to use "max-width: 400". It create problem and go on one side. I want to make it like bootstrap modal. Max-width: 400 and will be centered horizontally also. Please look at my code.

```js
// common close button
$('.mi-modal-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".mi-modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.mi-modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.mi-modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
.mi-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10%;
  width: 80%;  /* 94% + 3% +3% = 100% */
  max-width: 400px;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.mi-modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto auto !important;
}

.mi-modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mi-modal-header,
.mi-modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.mi-modal-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.mi-modal-close {
  margin: -0.5rem -0.5rem -0.5rem auto;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #edcfa5;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absoloute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  color: #000;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.mi-modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.mi-modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-content {
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}

.modal-footer>* {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="mi-modal-toggle" data-modal-id="modal1">Show modal</button>

<div class="mi-modal" data-modal-id="modal1">
  <div class="mi-modal-overlay mi-modal-toggle"></div>
  <div class="mi-modal-wrapper mi-modal-transition">
    <div class="mi-modal-header">
      <h2 class="mi-modal-heading">This is a modal</h2>
      <button class="mi-modal-close mi-modal-toggle">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="mi-modal-body">
      <div class="mi-modal-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="mi-btn btn-danger mi-ripple mi-ripple-light mi-modal-toggle">No</button>
      <button class="mi-btn btn-info mi-ripple mi-ripple-light">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrestling with margin and padding for centering, just use the standard left position and -50% x-axis translation.

```js
// common close button
$('.mi-modal-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".mi-modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.mi-modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.mi-modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mi-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.mi-modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mi-modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-transition {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mi-modal-header,
.mi-modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.mi-modal-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.mi-modal-close {
  margin: -0.5rem -0.5rem -0.5rem auto;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #edcfa5;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absoloute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  color: #000;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.mi-modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.mi-modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-content {
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}

.modal-footer>* {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="mi-modal-toggle" data-modal-id="modal1">Show modal</button>

<div class="mi-modal" data-modal-id="modal1">
  <div class="mi-modal-overlay mi-modal-toggle"></div>
  <div class="mi-modal-wrapper mi-modal-transition">
    <div class="mi-modal-header">
      <h2 class="mi-modal-heading">This is a modal</h2>
      <button class="mi-modal-close mi-modal-toggle">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="mi-modal-body">
      <div class="mi-modal-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="mi-btn btn-danger mi-ripple mi-ripple-light mi-modal-toggle">No</button>
      <button class="mi-btn btn-info mi-ripple mi-ripple-light">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For center alignment of modal add the following css code

```
.mi-modal.modal-visible {
    margin: auto;
    inset: 0;
}
.mi-modal-wrapper.mi-modal-transition {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

```js
// common close button
$('.mi-modal-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".mi-modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.mi-modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.mi-modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
.mi-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10%;
  width: 80%;  /* 94% + 3% +3% = 100% */
  max-width: 400px;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.mi-modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto auto !important;
}

.mi-modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-visible .mi-modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mi-modal-header,
.mi-modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.mi-modal-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.mi-modal-close {
  margin: -0.5rem -0.5rem -0.5rem auto;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #edcfa5;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absoloute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  color: #000;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  opacity: .5;
}

.mi-modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.mi-modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.mi-modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-content {
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mi-modal.modal-scroll .mi-modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}

.modal-footer>* {
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
.mi-modal.modal-visible {
margin: auto;
inset: 0;
}
.mi-modal-wrapper.mi-modal-transition {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="mi-modal-toggle" data-modal-id="modal1">Show modal</button>

<div class="mi-modal" data-modal-id="modal1">
  <div class="mi-modal-overlay mi-modal-toggle"></div>
  <div class="mi-modal-wrapper mi-modal-transition">
    <div class="mi-modal-header">
      <h2 class="mi-modal-heading">This is a modal</h2>
      <button class="mi-modal-close mi-modal-toggle">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="mi-modal-body">
      <div class="mi-modal-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="mi-btn btn-danger mi-ripple mi-ripple-light mi-modal-toggle">No</button>
      <button class="mi-btn btn-info mi-ripple mi-ripple-light">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Close, but you've lost the downward slide and there's a twitch on modal close.